# C++ Как обратиться к полю шаблона структуры по номеру в compile-time

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

```
template <class _Ty, class _Alloc = _STD allocator<_Ty>>
struct whisker {
public:
  enum class dir: uint8_t {
    BL = 0,  // поле base_left;
    BR = 1,  // поле base_right;
    HL = 2,  // поле hand_left;
    HR = 3   // поле hand_right;
  };

public:
  _Ty val;
  whisker* base_left;
  whisker* base_right;
  whisker* hand_right;
  whisker* hand_left;

  // Тут нужна функция, которая будет возвращать значение поля по его номеру.
  // Но она должна работать в compile-time, что-то вроде такого
  template <whisker::dir index>
  whisker* at();
 
  template <whisker::dir index == whisker::dir::BL>
  whisker* at(){
    return base_left;
  }

  template <whisker::dir index == whisker::dir::HR>
  whisker* at(){
    return hand_right;
  }

}
```

может вызываться, например, так:

```
int main(){
  whisker* wh;
  auto wh_base_left = wh.at<whisker::dir::BL>;
  auto wh_hand_right = wh.at<whisker::dir::HR>;
}
```

1. Как это сделать?
2. Или я вообще выбрал неправильный путь?
3. Если так неправильно, то как написать эту функцию, чтобы не было ветвлений if/else

Очень жду ваших ответов <3

Comment: Гуглите частичную специализацию шаблонов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо `template <whisker::dir index == whisker::dir::BL>` было попыткой реализовать специализацию для функции. Однако даже если бы синтаксис был верным, специализация для функции запрещена внутри класса. Однако даже если бы специализация функции была вынесена в пространство имен, специализация функции-члена класса не разрешается без специализации самого класса. Однако даже если добавить отдельный класс со статическим методом, который бы специализировался снаружи, использование параметра не-типа, зависящего от других параметров, не разрешается. Поэтому чтобы это все заработало надо будет еще написать тип-обертку.

```
#include <cstdint>

template<class x_T, class x_Alloc = void> struct
t_Whisker;

template<class x_T, class x_Alloc, typename t_Whisker<x_T, x_Alloc>::t_Dir x_dir> struct
t_TypeWrapper;

template<typename x_TypeWrapper> class
t_Dispatcher;

template <class x_T, class x_Alloc> struct
t_Whisker
{
    template<typename xx_TypeWrapper> friend class
    t_Dispatcher;

public:
    enum class t_Dir: ::std::uint8_t
    {
        bl = 0 // поле base_left;
    ,   br = 1 // поле base_right;
    ,   hl = 2 // поле hand_left;
    ,   hr = 3 // поле hand_right;
    };

public:
    x_T m_val;
    t_Whisker * m_base_left;
    t_Whisker * m_base_right;
    t_Whisker * m_hand_right;
    t_Whisker * m_hand_left;

    // Тут нужна функция, которая будет возвращать значение поля по его номеру.
    // Но она должна работать в compile-time, что-то вроде такого
    template <t_Dir x_dir>
    t_Whisker * at(void)
    {
        return t_Dispatcher<t_TypeWrapper<x_T, x_Alloc, x_dir>>::Fetch(*this);
    }
};

template<class x_T, class x_Alloc> class
t_Dispatcher<t_TypeWrapper<x_T, x_Alloc, t_Whisker<x_T, x_Alloc>::t_Dir::bl>> final
{
    public: static t_Whisker<x_T, x_Alloc> *
    Fetch(t_Whisker<x_T, x_Alloc> & self)
    {
        return self.m_base_left;
    }
};

int main()
{
    t_Whisker<int> wh{};
    wh.at<t_Whisker<int>::t_Dir::bl>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EYdvWs

Comment: Ну а в с++17 вместо этой перверсии можно использовать `if constexpr`...

Answer (score 2):

Не буду спорить, что теория не позволяет такое.

Но - just for info, не более того - конкретный компилятор VC++ (проверял на 2019 и 2017 с последними обновлениями) (а по некоторым признакам, код предназначен для VC++), такую специализацию съедает (если, конечно, убрать очевидные, не относящиеся к вопросу ошибки):

```
template <class _Ty, class _Alloc = _STD allocator<_Ty>>
struct whisker {
public:
    enum class dir: uint8_t {
        BL = 0,  // поле base_left;
        BR = 1,  // поле base_right;
        HL = 2,  // поле hand_left;
        HR = 3   // поле hand_right;
    };

public:
    _Ty val;
    whisker* base_left;
    whisker* base_right;
    whisker* hand_right;
    whisker* hand_left;

    // Тут нужна функция, которая будет возвращать значение поля по его номеру.
    // Но она должна работать в compile-time, что-то вроде такого
    template <whisker::dir index>
        whisker* at();

    template <>
        whisker* at<whisker::dir::BL>(){
            cout << "Left\n";
            return base_left;
        }

    template <>
        whisker* at<whisker::dir::HR>(){
            cout << "Right\n";
            return hand_right;
        }

};

int main(){
    whisker<int>* wh;
    auto wh_base_left = wh->at<whisker<int>::dir::BL>();
    auto wh_hand_right = wh->at<whisker<int>::dir::HR>();
}
```