# Способы решения error c2754 - "Частичная специализация не может иметь зависимый параметр шаблона, не являющийся типом"

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Проблема в том, что для вычисления **gcd** нужно передать тип числа(**Ty**), числа A(**Ax**) и Б(**Bx**) этого типа. Просто написать отдельные реализации для разных типов не выход, потому что есть более сложные алгоритмы с такой же проблемой. Там типов может быть не 2-3, а 10+, например при вычислении матриц и т.д.

Никаких вариантов, как решить эту проблему - в голову не приходит. Есть идеи?

```
// КЛАСС IntegralConstant 
template <class Ty, Ty Value>
struct IntegralConstant {
    static constexpr Ty value = Value;

    using value_type = Ty;
    using type       = IntegralConstant;

    constexpr explicit operator value_type() const noexcept {
        return value;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr value_type operator()() const noexcept {
        return value;
    }
};

// КЛАСС NumberInCompileTime
template <class Ty, Ty Number>
struct NumberInCompileTime : IntegralConstant<Ty, Number> {
};

// НОД - Наименьший Общий Делитель
template <class Ty, Ty Ax, Ty Bx>
struct gcdX : gcdX<Ty, Bx, Ax % Bx>::type {
}; // вычисляет НОД Ax и Bx

template <class Ty, Ty Ax>
struct gcdX<Ty, Ax, 0> : NumberInCompileTime<Ty, Ax> {
}; // вычисляет НОД Ax и 0

template <class Ty, Ty Ax, Ty Bx>
struct gcd : gcdX<Ty, abs<Ty, Ax>::value, abs<Ty, Bx>::value>::type {
}; // вычисляет НОД (Ax) и (Bx)

template <class Ty>
struct gcd<Ty, 0, 0> : NumberInCompileTime<Ty, 1> {
};
```

Comment: Оборачивать все константы в `std::integral_constant`? Non-type parameters — зло.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215170/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b2-compile-time/1215183#1215183